# Keeping a tidy global scope

Tags: php

I'm not exactly sure what to call this. Essentially, lets say I create a function that makes use of a bunch of supporting functions and variables but I don't want any of the supporting stuff to be accessible in the global scope so I can use short and simple names for them.

The best I can do in PHP right now is something like

```
$my_cool_function_spacer = " ";

function my_cool_function_add($a, $b) {
    global $my_cool_function_spacer;
    return $a . $my_cool_function_spacer . $b;
}

function my_cool_function($a, $b, $c) {
    return my_cool_function_add(my_cool_function_add($a, $b), $c);
}
```

Soo clunky to write. What I want to do instead, I'll illustrate in js:

```
var my_cool_function;

(function(){
    var spacer = " ";

    function add(a, b) {
        return a + spacer + b;
    }

    my_cool_function = function(a, b, c) {
        return add(add(a, b), c);
    }
})();
```

So in that snippet, I create the intrails of my_cool_function. The only part that can be used globally is my_cool_function and giving names like "spacer" or "add" is not a problem since they are restricted to the creating functions scope and can't overwrite anything outside.

Is there a way to follow the same kind of programming style in PHP?

Comment: Learn how to use classes, you can specify the accessibility of any method and variables in the class and use static functions for pure utility functions.

Comment: Your global looks like a constant.

Comment: @NigelRen if I use classes I still have to go through the class name which basically just replaces a _ with :: which is no better

Comment: Classes provide you a lot more than just namespaces,why do you think that OOP is widespread and at the core of most (if not all) frameworks and libraries.  If you look at your use of `global $my_cool_function_spacer;` - `global` is widely discouraged and this would instead be a private variable in the class.  In your case any code can change the value, classes give you some protection.  If all you want is a short name then keep going, but the rest of the PHP hoards (if not the IT world) will soon be leaving you behind.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using namespaces

```
namespace my_cool_function_ns {
    $spacer = " ";

    function add($a, $b) {
        global $spacer;
        return $a . $spacer . $b;
    }

    function my_cool_function($a, $b, $c) {
        return add(add($a, $b), $c);
    }
}

//    only downside is a bit clunky way to export to global namespace, maybe theres a better method?
namespace {
    function my_cool_function($a, $b, $c) {
        return my_cool_function_ns\my_cool_function($a, $b, $c);
    }
}
```